# How to access Children Node of Children in Tree view WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have treeview with checkboxes, want to access children node of children node in treeview.

This is how i made a treeview,I want to access level4 items check and uncheck value ,so that i can insert into database.

```
  private void FillingTreeDynamic()
    {
        Nodes.Clear();
        var data = dbobj.GetDataFromDataBase("", "Select * from Master");
        foreach (DataRowView dr in data)
        {
            var level_1_items = new Node() { Text = dr["MasterName"].ToString(),IsChecked=false};
            var details = dbobj.GetDataFromDataBase("", "Select * from Details where MasterID='"+Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"].ToString())+"'");
            foreach(DataRowView row in details)
            {
                var level_2_items = new Node() { Text = row["SubName"].ToString(),IsChecked=false};
                level_2_items.Parent.Add(level_1_items);
                level_1_items.Children.Add(level_2_items);
                var level_3_items = new Node() { Text ="View",IsChecked=false };
                level_3_items.Parent.Add(level_2_items);
                level_2_items.Children.Add(level_3_items);
                var dataView = dbobj.GetDataFromDataBase("","select * from ViewDetails");
                foreach (DataRowView rowview in dataView)
                {
                    var level_4_items = new Node() {Text=rowview["RightsName"].ToString(), IsChecked = false };
                    level_4_items.Parent.Add(level_3_items);
                    level_3_items.Children.Add(level_4_items);
                }

            }           

            Nodes.Add(level_1_items);
        }
        treeView.ItemsSource = Nodes;

    }
```

I am able to access the children nodes and its values as shown below.

```
 public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; private set; } 
 foreach (var parent in Nodes)
 {
  if (parent.IsChecked == true)
    {
      foreach (var item in parent.Children)
        {
           if (item.IsChecked == true)
               {
               }
           else
             {
             } 
       }
else
  {
  }     
 }
 }
```

How can i access the parent.Children of children nodes.Any idea how to access these children nodes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for your info a good article here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for this issue myself. This is how i accessed the parent.children of children nodes.

```
foreach (var parent in Nodes)
{


if (parent.IsChecked == true)
{
foreach (var item in parent.Children)
{
if (item.IsChecked == true)
{
}
else
{
} 
 foreach(var vtemp in item.Children)
 {
  foreach (var vtemp1 in vtemp.Children)
     {
       // and did my logic
     }
   }
}
else
{
}   
}
```